# Repairing malformed XML and powershell

Tags: xml, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

I am working with powershell where I have to read and parse a XML, which creates a scheduled task in windows task scheduler, as a string. It was all going well but as soon as I try to register the scheduled task it says the XML is malformed. And the precise problem is in the Arguments sub-tag under the Action tag in the XML file. 
Refer the following piece of code:

```
     <Arguments>-Command "& { & "./pl.ps1 {plname} run" } "</Arguments>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "&" character *must* be escaped. It must be put into the field as

```
<Arguments>-Command "&amp; { &amp; "./pl.ps1 {plname} run" } "</Arguments>
```

More information can be found by searching for "well-formed XML".

Comment: Thank you, Bob! I also ran into this issue. I created a schedule task, exported it, then edited the XML separately. I should have paid closer attention to Notepad++ highlighting the ampersand with a different color in the editor. Escaping the ampersand as you demonstrated solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could add CDATA to your tag:

```
<Arguments><![CDATA[-Command "& { & "./pl.ps1 {plname} run" } "]]></Arguments>
```

Within CDATA you can add about every character you want (except "]").